# How to paste a path in "ubuntu explorer" to rapidly access a folder?

Tags: shortcuts

I was browsing a local web page, I copied the address (`file:///media/383C4E753C4E2DE6/rar/lua/estacao/003/pessoas.htm`), and now I want to paste this path (`file:///media/383C4E753C4E2DE6/rar/lua/estacao/`) in the "ubuntu explorer" to rapidly access the folder `estacao`, and copy the folder `003`.

I also want to create a shortcut in the folder "document" using the path copied to clipboard.

Answer (score 33):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. The breadcrumb trail on the File browser will change to an address bar like the one you see in browsers. Paste the location and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> again to revert to the trail.

Comment: Sweet. Is there also a mouse-only way?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman nothing so quick, AFAIK. The equivalent of Ctrl-L is "Enter Location" in the "Go" Menu.

Comment: Thank you. To me, this is not intuitive at all - and quite an annoyance. A simple "paste" should suffice; why isn't that possible? "you just have to know this little trick"... this answer is helpful - but I consider this an UX fail.

Comment: True. This is really annoying and not intuitive at all. By double clicking or pasting into search icon should have option to paste path. Considering Linux is developer's OS, don't know why they are forcing people to navigate from UI rather pasting paths.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's quite old, but this page was the first result when I searched for a way to paste a path in ubuntu explorer.
And after finding the shortcut here, I [found a way](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/textual-path-ubuntu-20-04-files/) to make this change permanently with the following command in a terminal :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

Reversing to normal behavior can be done with :

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry
```